# Count Yes/No in multiple columns with unique rows

Tags: r

The dataset looks like this with 18 columns

```
group q1  q2  q3  name    q5 
a     yes yes no  blanket yes
b     no  no  no  water   yes
cc     yes no  no  food    no
d     yes no  no  utensils no
```

I want to just count how many yes/no each group answered excluding the 'name' column so I expect to output something like

```
group  yes  no 
a      15   10
b      7    18
cc     20   5
d      1    24
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: If there are 18 columns (18 *questions?*), how can you get rows where yes + no sums up to a number > 18?

Comment: It is an example.

Comment: That doesn’t really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `pivot_longer` to make your wide data to long data, then find the count based on the group and then revert back to wide form using `pivot_wider`

```r
library(tidyverse)

read.table(text = "group q1  q2  q3  name    q5 
a     yes yes no  blanket yes
b     no  no  no  water   yes
cc     yes no  no  food    no
d     yes no  no  utensils no", header = T) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-group) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  count(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [4]
#>   group    no   yes
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 a         1     3
#> 2 b         3     1
#> 3 cc        3     1
#> 4 d         3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `apply` :

```
cols <- grep('q\\d+', names(df))
cbind(df[1], t(apply(df[cols], 1, table)))

#  group no yes
#1     a  1   3
#2     b  3   1
#3    cc  3   1
#4     d  3   1
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option with `dcast` + `table`

```
dcast(
  setDT(df)[,
    data.table(table(unlist(.SD))),
    group,
    .SDcols = patterns("^q")
  ],
  group ~ V1
)
```

gives

```
   group no yes
1:     a  1   3
2:     b  3   1
3:    cc  3   1
4:     d  3   1
```